# How to use different variables in my test cases with using same keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to use same keyword with different variables. 
Example: For entering spacekey and spacename during first space creation Variables Spacekey1 and Spacename1 are set and used and for the second space creation Spacekey2 and Spacename2 will be used.

And how can I ensure that in case of Spacekey1 is used, Spacename1 should be used if needed?

Here is my code:

*** Variables *** 
${TEST_PREFIX}     VVV

&{KEY_PARAMS}      key1=${SPACE_KEY1}      key2=${SPACE_KEY2} 
&{NAME_PARAMS}      name1=${SPACE_NAME1}      name2=${SPACE_NAME2}

${TEST_SPACE}      ${TEST_SYSTEM}/display/${SPACE_KEY}/ 
${TEST_SPACE2}      ${TEST_SYSTEM}/display/${SPACE_KEY2}/ 
${TEST_PAGE}       ${TEST_SYSTEM}/display/${SPACE_KEY}/${PAGE_NAME} 
${TEST_PAGE2}       ${TEST_SYSTEM}/display/${SPACE_KEY}/${PAGE_NAME2}

*** Test Cases ***
Create Space 
[Documentation]  Create a Space 
Click Menu
**Enter Space Name and Space Key     &{KEY_PARAMS.key1}     &{NAME_PARAMS.name1}**
Click Create Button 
Go To      ${TEST_SPACE}

Create Space2 
[Documentation]  Create a Space2 
Click Menu 
**Enter Space Name and Space Key     &{KEY_PARAMS.key2}      &{NAME_PARAMS.name2}** 
Click Create Button 
Go To      ${TEST_SPACE2}

*** Keywords *** 
Generate SpaceKey 
[Documentation]  Create New SpaceKey 
${TEST_RUN_NUMBER}     Generate Test Case Number 
&{KEY_PARAMS}     Set Variable      ${TEST_PREFIX}${TEST_RUN_NUMBER} 
Set Suite Variable      &{KEY_PARAMS} 
Create Session       API Testing       ${TEST_SYSTEM} 
${Get_Response}     GET on Session       API Testing      /rest/api/space/${SPACE_KEY}      expected_status=any 
IF  "<Response [200]>" == "${Get_Response}" 
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds        1 times       1 sec       Generate SpaceKey 
Log  Executed as long as the condition for Space Key is True. 
END 
[Return]     &{KEY_PARAMS}

Generate SpaceName 
[Documentation]  Create New SpaceName 
${NAME_PARAMS}     Set Variable       SPACE${TEST_PREFIX}${TEST_RUN_NUMBER} 
Set Suite Variable       name_params=${SPACE_NAME}

Enter Space Name and Space Key 
Generate SpaceKey       &{KEY_PARAMS} 
Generate SpaceName      &{NAME_PARAMS} 
Click Element     name:name 
Input Text      name:name      ${SPACE_NAME} 
Click Element     name:spaceKey 
Input Text     name:spaceKey     ${SPACE_KEY}

I am getting Errors:

PS C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest> robot generate_testcase_number.robot 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 14: Setting variable '&{KEY_PARAMS}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_KEY1}' not found. 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 15: Setting variable '&{NAME_PARAMS}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_NAME1}' not found. 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 16: Setting variable '&{PAGE_PARAMS}' failed: Variable '${PAGE_NAME1}' not found. 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\resources\variables.robot' on line 14: Setting variable '&{PARAMS}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_KEY1}' not found. 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 19: Setting variable '${TEST_PAGE}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_KEY}' not found. Did you mean:
${SPACE} 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 20: Setting variable '${TEST_PAGE2}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_KEY}' not found. Did you mean:
${SPACE} 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 17: Setting variable '${TEST_SPACE}' failed: Variable '${SPACE_KEY}' not found. Did you mean:
${SPACE} 
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\uef8fe\Docupedia\atest\generate_testcase_number.robot' on line 18: Setting variable '${TEST_SPACE2}' failed: Variable '${
SPACE_KEY2}' not found. 
============================================================================== 
Generate Testcase Number 
==============================================================================

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50587/devtools/browser/45e2afb8-e30d-4d7c-b66c-78e82b8a5b48 
Create Docupedia Bosch Blank Space :: Create a Docupedia Bosch Bla... | FAIL | 
Resolving variable '&{KEY_PARAMS.key1}' failed: Variable '${KEY_PARAMS}' not found.

Comment: your code is very extensive. It would be easier to answer your question if you had used the [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)But I see you use no [user keyword arguments](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-arguments) perhaps that is a way to go

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. It's impossible to read.